# Tracking down reason for connection refused on 8th successive ssh connection

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I am using a code deployment service that connects to my server and execute commands. It connects, run some commands, disconnects and repeat.

I am always getting connection refused on the 8th connection within the same deployment.

From the service itself, all I can see is `ssh: connect to host xxx port 22: Connection refused`

I only see the connecting and disconnecting in `/var/log/auth.log` -- No connection refused errors.

For reference this is what I see in `auth.log`:

```
Accepted publickey for envoyer from 159.203.66.107 port 50177 ssh2: RSA
...
Received disconnect from 159.203.66.107 port 50177:11: disconnected by user
Disconnected from 159.203.66.107 port 50177
pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user envoyer
Removed session 5996.
... repeated
```

How can I find out why it's refusing connection?

I am using DigitalOcean LAMP server.

Comment: If your logs don't show enough information, you might try to increase their verbosity.

Comment: @HBruijn How do I do that? FYI I do see random connection failures from unknown IP addresses in `auth.log`. Probably from bots trying their luck on random servers. Could there be rate limiters installed that I do not know of?

Comment: `man sshd_config` /LogLevel

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems, check your IPtables (`iptables -L`) and see if you have a `hitcount` set, something similar to this (2nd line):

```
Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
           tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 30 hit_count: 4 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255 reject-with tcp-reset
```

The key parameter is `hit_count` and also take a look at UPDATE.

In my case I was getting rejections after 3 tries, and nothing in the logs either.

Answer (score 0):

On a Digital Ocean server with a Docker image, we had the same.

Was clearly shown in the logs as:

`$ sudo grep UFW /var/logs
...
Sep 11 08:29:21 <hostname> kernel: [5334027.195168] [UFW LIMIT BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=96:38:e8:52:00:e7:f4:a7:39:d7:82:7d:08:00 SRC=xx.xx.xx.xx DST=xx.xx.xx.xx LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=30729 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53180 DPT=22 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 CWR ECE SYN URGP=0`

It looks like the server was set-up with the feature:

`ufw limit ssh`

as described in https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-limiting-ssh-connections-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-debian/

Our work-around, since we only use ssh keys and no passwords, was to change the LIMIT rule into an ALLOW rule.

`root@hostname:/var/log# sudo ufw status
Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         LIMIT       Anywhere

...
root@hostname:/var/log# sudo ufw allow ssh
Rule updated
Rule updated (v6)
root@hostname:/var/log# sudo ufw status
Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere`